# Set class to active in table row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a bit limited in being able to get what I want and I am hoping maybe there is a way to do this, either with CSS (which I doubt) or javascript.

I have a table as seen below where drupal will assign the link an "active" class. This is great, but I would like to change the CSS of the entire row that the active link is in and I just can't automate that with drupal. Is there anyway to see which page the user is on and then add a class or id to the row (tr) that has the current link?

```
<table class="views-table cols-0" thmr="thmr_80">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd views-row-first">
      <td class="views-field views-field-counter">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>          
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="views-field views-field-counter">
        <a href="#" class="active">Link 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That would be great if I could do that. How can I target a parent when referencing the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a class to the row based on the active anchor, you could use `closest()` (if using jQuery), and just style the class you decide to give that row with CSS.

```
$(function() {
    $('.views-table a.active').closest('tr').addClass('active_row');
});
```

CSS

```
.active_row {color: green; height: 300px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have no idea what to do with that. :) Any way to explain a bit more?

Comment: Is your site using jQuery, I guess I assumed it was as most people do these days ?

Comment: Yeah it is actually, but I dont have much experience with jquery so I don't know where to put that line.

Comment: Added a little bit, now just add that anywhere, inside script tags or in an external javascript file, and it should add the class to the row.

Comment: Amazing! You just made my day. Thanks @adeneo!!

Comment: The question is not tagged with, nor mentions, jQuery. This shouldn't be the accepted answer unless the question is updated or at the very least a non-jQuery answer is provided too

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script src="/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('td.views-field a.active').css("color","900");
   });
   </script>


   <table class="views-table cols-0" thmr="thmr_80">
     <tbody>
       <tr class="odd views-row-first">
         <td class="views-field views-field-counter">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>          
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="even">
         <td class="views-field views-field-counter">
           <a href="#" class="active">Link 2</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @vainglory07. This would also work just as above. Thanks for your time!